# What does an @ do in assembly?

Tags: masm

```
call dword ptr __imp__VirtualProtect@16
```

What exactly is the @ doing? Is it just part of the name of the function or? I've seen this in multiple locations and am wondering what it stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the symbol name. The symbol name differs from the function name since function names aren't unique. See [Name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Answer (score 1):

It means that a call to PROC _*imp*_VirtualProtect takes 16 bytes of parameters (like 4 DWORDs, or 2 DWORDs and 4 WORDs, or... )

The @16 is generated in the output object code by MASM when the PROC is defined (CDECL or STDCALL). The linker sees the "mangled" name.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, it's just part of the function name here.